# Custom theme and sherlockActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I am doing a personal theme to use holo widget in 2.3 android.

I did this:

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="AppThemes" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">

    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme.DropDown</item>

    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

the problem is that widgets don't take the correct style but take the default style. I tried to force assign the @style/EditTextAppTheme at an edittext and it worked.. so the problem is that the theme don't apply.

any idea?

update: the theme apply and work good..the solo problem is some edittext inside a dialog that show with the standard theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the holo theme style in an App for `API 10` and below, you can use `HoloEverywhere`. It's well integrated with `ActionBarSherlock`. `ActionBarSherlock` is included as a subproject. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a customized Theme you have to set these style attributes in your Application theme. Then apply this theme to the whole App or to a single Activity by defining it in the manifest or setting it programmaticaly in the onCreate() method.

For example(for ABS):

```
<style name="Theme.myStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme.DropDown</item>

<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

And then set this theme to your Application or your Activity in the Manifest with:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.myStyle"
```

or programmatically:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme.myStyle);
```

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
        >

Comment: Perhaps you set an other theme to your Activity.

Comment: no, only on the application tag. (this is why i did this thread :D)

Comment: hmmm this is indeed strange :D

Comment: i added a new thing in my original question